# ParseUser.getCurrentUser() confusion

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm using [Parse](https://www.parse.com/) as the backend.

To check if the user is logged in I use `ParseUser.getCurrentUser()`. What I don't understand is, if the user changes his password from somewhere else (another device, the web-client), will this ParseUser return with some kind of error?

I don't think it does a check on the server, so I think it just returns the last saved user. This mean that I can continue to use this user (with an old password) or will I get a "wrong credential" response on the first request to the servers?

If I don't get it, will I at least get it when setting an ACL with `parseObject.setACL(new ParseACL(ParseUser.getCurrentUser()));`?

Answer (score 0):

Try same action on yahoo in 2 open browsers of different types and see what you get?

Each client's been handed a token value by the respective servers and until the token expire will not be prompt for a new logon.

Well IMO Parse work very similar except the lease on Parse token never expire.

Response to the original parse logon contain the token value which the SDK may retain. Details are in the docs section on Rest api / user logon...

So, if a diff client change password but the token lease over on some other client never expire, the other client stays logged in.